# Stored procedure not working in context of application

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a process which is pushing data into my database. One table in the database is for storing the users (`tblUsers`) I get from the process (the process communicates with the cloud).

The columns of `tblUsers` are:

```
sid  -  id1  -  id2  -  userId  -  username  -  timestampt
```

After data is pushed into this table I have several entries where sid, id1, id2, userid and username are equal. To eliminate them I'm using the following SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @tbl table
(
    sid int,
    id1 int,
    id2 int, 
    userId int,
    userName varchar(40),
    timestamp char(14),
    rn int  
)

insert into @tbl 
   select 
       *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id1, id2, userId, userName order by timestamp desc) as rn
    from dbo.tblUsers

update r
set r.userIdRef = t2.sid
from dbo.tblContracts r
join @tbl t1 on r.userIdRef = t1.sid
join @tbl t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
                and t1.id2 = t2.id2
                and t1.userId = t2.userId
                and t1.userName = t2.userName
                and t1.sid <> t2.sid
                and t2.rn = 1

update r
set r.userIdRef = t2.sid
from dbo.tblTimes r
join @tbl t1 on r.userIdRef = t1.sid
join @tbl t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id1
                and t1.id2 = t2.id2
                and t1.userId = t2.userId
                and t1.userName = t2.userName
                and t1.sid <> t2.sid
                and t2.rn = 1

delete m
from dbo.tblUsers m
join @tbl t on m.sid = t.sid
where t.rn > 1
```

If I call this directly in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, it just works fine.

If I create a stored procedure with this code and call it in Management Studio, it also just works fine.

Now if I call the stored procedure from my C++ application it doesn't work. I get an error code `-1` when I call `SQLRETURN rc = SQLExecute(sqlHandle);` The handle is valid. I already checked that.

Can anybody tell me what the problem in this context is?

Comment: Where do you get the -1 from?

Comment: In the debugger of my application

Comment: Yes, but from where does it come in your C++ code? Which function returns that value?

Comment: Have you tried calling [SQLError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716312(v=vs.85).aspx) to figure out what the error is? Or perhaps these days it's better to use SQLGetDiagRec

Comment: Ok. `SQLGetDiagRec` told me, that the storedprocedure didn't have enough rights to execute

Comment: Perhaps check the user you are connecting with?